# Editar usando o foreach (Editado)

Tags: php, codeigniter

Boa noite. Tenho um formulário onde quero editar umas informações de um determinado setor. Sendo que os epis do select são um foreach do banco, porém quero que os que eu quero editar fiquem selecionados, porém, além de selecionar eles estão sendo duplicados. Segue o código:

```
<select title="Selecione os EPIs" multiple>

   <?php 

      $epi_explode = explode(',', $result->setor_EPI);

      foreach ($epis as $epi)
      { 
           foreach ($epi_explode as $epi_array)
           { ?>                   
              <option <?=$epi_array == $epi->epi_Nome ? 'selected' : '';?> > 
                  <?=$epi->epi_Nome?>
              </option>

     <?php } } ?>

</select>
```

Controler:

```
    public function index()
{   
    $data = array
    (
        'title' => 'Edição de Setores',
        'epis' => $this->setor_model->getEpis(),
    );

    $this->load->view('frame/cabecalho');
    $this->load->view('frame/navegacao');
    $this->load->view('setor/cadastro', $data);
}
```

Model da Query.

```
    public function getEpis()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('epi');
    return $this->db->get()->result();         
}
```

Segue a imagem de como lista os resultados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O select lista dos os equipamento de epi, porem quero que somente os que estão no banco de dados fiquem selecionados, pois isso é uma pagina de editar tal setor.

Comment: Cole também o resultado do loop que aparece após executar o código para uma melhor compreensão.

Comment: Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: coloca a estrutura do banco aqui, a QUERY, deixa completa a pergunta, senão fica difícil